# How to mock static java method from kotlin , mockkStatic not working

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockk

I want to mock static method of java class from Kotlin test case.

I am using below code that does not work.

It always called actual method.

```
mockkStatic(Aes::class)
every { Aes.decrypt(PASSWORD, SECRET_KEY) } returns PASSWORD
```

Actual method in java class:

```
public static String decrypt(String text, String secretKey) {}
```

Comment: What is your test-case?

Comment: toward  api call nested private method are there

Answer (score 3):

The good strategy for this is to use wrapper objects around static methods if there is no other way around (for example static method belongs to 3rd party library)

```kotlin
class AESWrapper {

    fun decrypt(String text, String secretKey) {
        return Aes.decrypt(text, secretKey)
    }

}
```

There are other solutions like PowerMock, but then you need to use PowerMockRunner as I remember which can limit you in the future